# Vue JS How to catch errors globally and display them in a top level component

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, global

I have set up Vue so that I have a top level AppLayout component which just includes a Navigation Menu component, the router-view and, which uses v-if to optionally display an ErrorDisplay component if the error data item is set. I set this from an err state variable in the Vuex store.

That is where I want to get to. However, I think the problem is more fundamental.

In a lower component, I have a submit function that gets called when I click the submit button. To test error handling I have put

throw new Error('Cannot Submit');

In my Main.js I have

handlers for window.orerror, window.addEventListner, Vue.config.errorhandler, Vue.config.warnhandler

All of these should just call the errHandler function, which just calls an action to update the err variable in the state. The hope being that this will then result in the ErrorDisplay component showing on my top level component.

However, I have console.log statements as the first statement in all the above handlers and in my errHandler function. None of these console.logs are getting executed.

In the Console in Chrome, I am just seeing 
[vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: Cannot Submit"

So it is getting the text from my throw, but none of the error handlers seem to be capturing this?

Comment: Instead of using Throw, I tried modifying a call to axios so it had an invalid end point, then catching the error and calling my global errHandler with the e error returned. However, it seems that somehow the window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection',function(event) is getting called. However, this is then erroring saying that Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. I don't know what to do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Vue provides Global configuration `config.errorHandler` to capture error inside Vue components Globally.

As per Official Docs

> Assign a handler for uncaught errors during component to render function and watchers. The handler gets called with the error and the Vue instance.

This is how it can be used:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
  // handle error
  // `info` is a Vue-specific error info, e.g. which lifecycle hook
  // the error was found in. Only available in 2.2.0+
}
```

Official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler)

Hope this helps!

Comment: As per my original question, I already have Vue,config.errorHandler in my code, but the very first line is a console.log and that is not getting called. It seems that Vue doesn't call this for a thrown error. See this link for an example. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/50200/). Seems rather poor. I had less trouble creating a global error handler in Excel VBA than I have had in Vue and Microsoft have not updated VBA for years.

Answer (score 0):

Did more research and I think someone may have already raised a bug report with Vue for this
[PR on Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/5709)
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/5709

So it looks like the problem is that the way that I am trying to test this isn't being caught.